# Sending sms using transactional api from sfmc to Indian mobile number

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript, journey, jira-mobile-connect

I have created sms in content builder. Then tried triggering it to Indian mobile number

But I didn't receive any sms. In marketing cloud, its showing the sms is delivered.

I tried triggering to the following mobile number. eg: 91965566****

I need the working payload. And am I following the correct steps for triggering sms to Indian mobile number